# Web API - Mapping request URL and body parameters to method arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, routes

I should start by showing you my `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration configuration)
{
     configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("noKey",
                                       "{controller}");

     configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("oneKey",
                                       "{controller}/{id}");

     configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("twoKeys",
                                       "{controller}/{firstKey}/{secondKey}");

     // SomeProperty -> someProperty
     var jsonFormatter = configuration.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
     jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
}
```

I have the following base class:

```
public abstract class RestController<Key, PostDTO, PutDTO, QueryData>
{
      // ...

      protected abstract Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(Key id, PutDTO dto);

      // ...

      [HttpPut]
      [ValidateArgument("dto")]
      public async Task<IHttpActionResult> BasePut([FromUri] Key id, [FromBody] PutDTO dto)
      {
            return await Put(id, dto);
      }
}
```

The `ValidateArgumentAttribute` is a custom attribute that I made that validates the input DTO.

I am trying to call this method like this:

```
HTTP PUT - /users/mcicero
```

As you can see, I have a `UsersController` (/users) and I want to make a PUT request to the entity with key `mcicero` (/users/mcicero).

The DTO is sent along the request payload, which is represented by the `[FromBody]` parameter attribute.

I am getting, however, a `404 Not Found` response as if the endpoint cannot be resolved into a valid route.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: what is actual type of "Key" ?

Comment: @hazjack In this example (UsersController), it is of type `string`

Comment: did you double check the url / port ? I think it should have to work. My similar case works fine  :)

Comment: @hazjack Everything seems to look normal for me. How did you manage it to work? Could it be maybe because of the three configured routes?

Answer (score 1):

After fighting with this **for hours**... I finally managed to find a solution to the problem (Correct me if this is bad)

I had to enable all verbs (`verb="*"`) to the `ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0` handler:

**Web.config**

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```